# SQLite - I'm getting missing information from DB to List<> on c#

Tags: c#, list, sqlite

Henlo, i am trying to get usernames from a database and it seems im missing index 0. 
Database explanation:

- id:1 username: player 1
- id:2 username: player 2
- id:3 username: player 3 etc... until player 7

  ```
      List<string> Uname = new List<string>();         
      SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
      connection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=e:\\GridDB\\users.db");
      connection.Open();
      string query = "SELECT username FROM players";
      SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
      using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
              foreach (var item in rdr)
              {
                  Uname.Add(rdr["username"].ToString());

              }                    
          }
          rdr.Close();
          connection.Close();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < Uname.Count; i++)
      {
           TB.AppendText(Uname[i] + "\n");
      }
  ```

and this is my output:

```
player 2

player 3

player 4

player 5

player 6

player 7
```

problem is i need player 1 too =)

Comment: The inner for-each loop is not required, it only ever looks at one column but does it for every column. I'm surprised you aren't getting duplicates in the List (number of columns)...

Comment: Have you debugged, Did you check what is value stored in List? What values are stored in `rdr`

Comment: Removing Foreach fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you iterating over SqlDataReader once again after the while statement?

This works:

```
   List<string> Uname = new List<string>();         
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=e:\\GridDB\\users.db");
    connection.Open();
    string query = "SELECT username FROM players";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           Uname.Add(rdr["username"].ToString());         
        }
        rdr.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Uname.Count; i++)
    {
         TB.AppendText(Uname[i] + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: yeah my logic was wrong.Removing foreach solves problem like you did. ty. im learning working with databases atm. thanks again.